# Bifurcation diagram by C++ of the non-local elastica

Tags: c++, methods, elastica, discretization, chaos

I have tried to do a simulation using C++ of the equation of non-local elastica defined by the following system
[image]

Using the following discretization

[image]

with the boundary condition
[image] and by sitting lc=1/(6*sqrt(3)), but I did not arrive to the  bifurcation diagram  like in the following image,
[image]

This is the code that I have used.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#define PI 3.14
using namespace std;
main (){
 int i,n,m;
double a=0,b=PI,h,l,BETA=PI*PI;
 double X[500],V[500], T[500];
 cout<<"donne n=";
 cin>>n;
 l=1./(2*n*sqrt(3));
ofstream SOL("eringen.txt");
V[0]=0;
V[100]=0;
X[0]=5;
//SOL << X[0]<<"\t"<< V[0] << endl;

 for (m=1; m<=100; m++)
{
for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
 {
    X[i]=X[i-1]+(1./m)*V[i-1];
        V[i]=V[i-1]-(1./m)*BETA*(1+l*l*V[i-1]*V[i-1])*sin(X[i])*(1./(1-BETA*l*l*cos(X[i])));
        SOL << X[i-1]<<"\t"<< V[i-1] << endl;   
}
}
 FILE *fp = popen("gnuplot", "w");
fprintf(fp,"plot 'eringen.txt'  ;\  pause mouse \n");
cin.get();
 pclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you varying `m`? From both the formulas and the plot, it looks like `m` is a constant for each curve, and in the plots it's either 1000 or 10000. In your code you are varying `m` from 1 to 100 in a single curve.

Comment: @G.Sliepen You're right, also `theta` varied from `0` to `pi` and `beta` from `0` to `8*pi^2`, but  I do not understand how to make this implementation.

Comment: Using `for`-loops, but if you only want to get curves for `m = 1000` and `m = 10000`, then write: `for(int m: {1000, 10000}) {...}`.